# Why I need to specify the folder to see the index.html in Tomcat 10

Tags: html, web, tomcat

I've created a web app in NetBeans with Tomcat 10 and some file, one of them is the `index.html` file. I want that when I search this `http://localhost:8080` in the browser, shows the `index.html` file. Right now when I search `http://localhost:8080` it shows the tomcat init page, and I don't really understand why.

I though that maybe I need to specify something in the `context.xml` file. Right now, the project is inside a folder named Prac, and the content of `context.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/Prac"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should tomcat 9 because tomcat 10 not working stable.

Comment: Thanks!! I change to tomcat 9 and the problem is solved

Comment: I'm glad can you give plus points

Comment: How can I give you plus points?